# Windows Server 2012 Setting up "Non-interactive" administrator account, just for giving permission

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

My company is currently in the process of becoming cyber essential certified so we need to increase admin account security to pass.

My question is:
How to setup an admin account that can't login into a session on windows but can give permission to run services. For example using the "run as administrator" feature to open applications that need admin permission.

this would be to prevent admins to have direct access to the internet and work as a form of two-factor authentication as admins will need their standard user account alongside the admin account.

I have tried using GPO settings but could not find anything useful, please help!

Thank you.

Comment: They need to restart service for what purpose ? as if a service crashed it need to be investigated why, and usually it's a senior admin that will do the task

Answer (score 1):

Runas requires the ability to logon interactively/locally.

One option may be to use the "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services" Windows right, and apply it to the security group for which the administrator accounts are a member.  That would mitigate some of the lateral movement for servers, but they would still be able to logon to the console.

For workstations, another option may be to require use of a local account for local administrative functions, and use a product such as Microsoft LAPS to manage the passwords and rotation.

Comment: thanks whilst looking up what you where saying i found this: http://www.authlite.com/kb/allow-runas-but-block-interactive-logon/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works pretty well for this, the link is here:
http://www.authlite.com/kb/allow-runas-but-block-interactive-logon/

it will allow you to make accounts that give permissions, but still are unable to sign in.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a solution because you are still allowing interactive logons. In security lexicon, this *may* be referred to as a compensating control. But it isn't a very good compensating control because it is so easy to defeat and you aren't alarming on the usage with your SIEM.